# MS Query SQL - Append Data

Tags: sql, excel

Is it possible to use MS Query to append rows from one Excel worksheet into another in the same workbook? And specifically what would the SQL be to accomplish it?

To give a bit of background: I have a worksheet that connects to a SQL Server database and I'd like to append the rows it returns to another worksheet and thereby create an audit trail.

Hope that makes some sort of sense!

Thanks.

Comment: you can use excel macros to do that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MS Query only replaces the data in a a spreadsheet.  An option would be to create a macro you run after you update the query to copy any records to a separate audit worksheet.

One other option is to create the audit trail in sql server (that might be a bit more than you want to tackle though)

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I wanted to find a non-VBA solution and managed to by using UNION ALL.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for putting the answer in

Answer (score 0):

I used UNION ALL in my audit sheet to join the aduit sheet with the SQL Server sheet:

```
SELECT *
FROM Audit
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM SQLServer
```